# How to effectively use useEffect

Tags: reactjs, api

I'm currently learning how to use hooks in React and I'm currently on useEffect. For my last couple of projects I've been using the same API to pull data from (Opendota) and just doing different ways of calling the data. Any ideas of why this doesn't work? I assume I'm missing something important when it pretains to useEffect

heroes.services

```
import React from 'react'

const getStatsById = heroId => async () => {
    const resp = await fetch("https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats");
    const statsList = await resp.json();
    return statsList.find(stats => stats.id === heroId)
};

export {getStatsById};
```

Herodropdown

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import {getStatsById} from '../services/heroes.service.js'


const Herodropdown = () => {
    useEffect(getStatsById(heroId));
    return (
        <h2> {heroId}</h2>

        )
}
export default Herodropdown
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? API call isn't fired? You don't do anything with the response from the API. You just return it, but it's not saved into state. You should also include the list of dependencies for your effect

Comment: I'm thinking the formatting may be wrong. Try running useEffect(() => getStatsById(heroId)) instead

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: @jayce444 The {heroId} is being called undefined in the Herodropdown, so I was trying to see if that reason was useEffect

Comment: I agree with @EdgarCuarezma I believe the useEffect format is incorrect. Alongside this you are not specifying the dependency array which could cause infinite loops, etc. That should also be outlined in the link that EdgarCuarezma sent. I would recommend setting up eslint to help catching some of these errors using the react-hooks eslint plugin! Would assist with learning the new hooks syntax. Good luck :D

Comment: @4156 ok so where is `heroId` defined? I don't see it defined anywhere in Herodropdown. Also his format for `useEffect` first argument is ok, cos `getStatsById` returns a function not a value

Comment: @jayce444 Let me back up first, I was just throwing something together at first. I want to be able to call heroes.services to handle all of my api calling. I was just testing to see if that code worked and I'm unsure how to write a test for it. I assumed useEffect was the best option but after tinkering I couldn't find a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> const Herodropdown = () => {
>     useEffect(getStatsById(heroId));
>     return (
>       <h2> {heroId}</h2>
>     )
>   }
> ```

not defined `heroId`, the same as `getStatsById(undefined)`

but this only calls API ... probably you need to use a result of API call:

```
  const Herodropdown = (heroId) => {
    const [stats, setStats] = useState(null);
    useEffect( () => { setStats( getStatsById(heroId) ) } );
    return (
      <>
        <h2> {heroId}</h2>
        stats: {stats}
      </>
    )
  }
```

... but we don't need to use effect on every render, we should define that it should be fired only on `heroId` change:

```
      useEffect( () => { setStats( getStatsById(heroId) ) }, [heroId] );
```

It can be `[]` for one time/initial call.

Comment: I decided to go with your solution and while it seems like the best bet, I'm still getting some errors. It seems I'm getting something with setStats is not a function

Comment: sorry, I defined it wrongly ... should be `const [stats, setStats] = useState(null);`